# How to keep a project on track between two departments where there is very little oversight

Tags: project-management, meetings

I'm a sys admin that leads a weekly meeting between two departments for the upgrade of a system that has reached end of life and we are trying to get it upgraded to a supported platform.  We've been meeting for quite some time now, probably about two years and not reaching the end goal of getting the system upgraded.

Those attending the meeting are all techs.  I'm in Department A and I work mainly with contractors and a manager who has a technical background.  The other department will be known as Department B and is mainly made up of contractors too and a Manager who isn't technical.  Also want to point out that no managers rarely ever attend except when there is an major issue.  However when I meet with my Manager and we talk about current events and various status updates, the response is often, "I thought that was upgraded already."  For these reasons, I would like to know your thoughts on the following:

- Department B has some ideas of some new technology they want to implement; however they never come to the table with any solid ideas or any type of road map on getting from point A to point B
- I would like to send out weekly updates to both departments and status checks saying this is where we are at; however Department B doesn't really read or respond to anything that I've written via email.  Plus, I'm busy enough as it is.  Their manager doesn't seem to do a good job in supervising his contractors either
- Check in with both managers to keep things on track that way there is no "I thought this was done" or contractors from Dept B didn't get what needed to be done

Background on me:  I hold a Masters in MIS and I am familiar with project management skills; most of my experience has been in IT Operations (PC Support, Network Admin and now Sys Admin); a lot of places I've worked at don't seem to regard project management in high regards and I get a sense of that here too.

Comment: Who determined that it was a business goal to upgrade this system?

Comment: Mainly the techs, however the managers agreed with us.

Answer (score 2):

From this description, the entire project is ********.

You've got two teams of tech people working completely independently, with little or no management oversight and no accountability. Your manager (from his response) clearly thinks that more progress has been made than actually has, and after two years of little to no progress one of the teams is still banding around a vague idea of a technology they want to use with no particular idea how.

Sometimes, you get to the position where it's better to just cut your losses and run - it sounds like the project may have reached that point.

If you really want to get it back on track, then you need a full time technical project manager / lead who's responsible for:

- Being a single point of contact for the entire project
- Deciding on a long term schedule for getting the whole thing implemented
- Running and structuring the weekly meetings to agree a list of deliverables for the coming week
- Listening to suggestions of any specific libraries / technologies, and then making the final decision around those suggestions
- Holding teams and team members to account if deliverables aren't met on a regular basis

Tech lead and project manager could be split up into two roles of course, but someone needs to be doing all the tasks above, and in a situation like this, they need to be doing these tasks *exceptionally well* to bring the project back on track.

Comment: So what is a good way to hold teams and team members accountable?  These are the same people in Dept B that when I send them an email, they deny getting the email and if they get the email, they don't even bother to read it.  Also have an issue where we have an reoccurring meeting weekly, people from Dept B will email me and ask if the meeting is happening.

Comment: Get firm, get authority (if you need it) and start calling them out on blatant lies. If they deny getting emails, forward them to them every so often until you get a response acknowledging they've received it. If they ask if the meeting is happening, don't just say "yes", say "of course, you should assume the meeting is happening as per usual unless you hear otherwise." Likewise start putting deadlines on action items in emails, and if they're not met, follow up and ask why. This sort of situation needs a very *active* project management role if you've a hope of holding people to account.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that department A and department B need to collaborate in order to achieve "the end goal of getting a system upgraded" which did not happen (yet). You are concerned because you don't feel in control of the closure process, but still responsible about it.

It is important to clarify some aspects that seem out of order (although normal in many companies :) ).

1. Who is the project manager? You seem more concerned about this project than the managers of the departments.. This needs to be clarified with them. If it is you, then take more lead and read forward. If not, then stop worrying and continue with the status quo..
2. What is the definition of success of your project? The definition of success has to include scope (what?), timeline(when?), resources(who?) and must be very detailed at this stage. e.g. "flying to Mars" is not a valid definition of success. But "flying to Mars by December 2021 with the cost of $100" is.
3. Who are the stakeholders of this project? Who is the end user? Who can alter the definition of success of this project? Who has a great impact on this success?

Note that "upgrade the system" is not definition of success, it is just something vague and irrelevant. What exactly do the stakeholders want to see in the upgraded system as opposed to the old one? What happens if the system is not upgraded or partially upgraded? (and no, answers like "Kelly will be very upset if we don't do this" are not valid, unless Kelly can articulate a business reason why she is upset and why "this" has to be done). Can the upgrade be done gradually?

Once you have clarified the definition of success and the stakeholders, you can put up/restructure a plan with actionable items (who needs to do each item and by when) towards the goal as articulated in the definition of success (and as you suggest yourself too, in point 2). I suggest to include in this plan also WHAT WAS DONE (not only what is left to be done), to avoid statements like "I thought this was done". Monitor the plan on a weekly basis (keep the weekly discussions ON THE PLAN only) highlighting delays/blockers and  dependencies and asking stakeholders approval for any change in the plan. Keep the plan concise and itemized. Stakeholders MUST BE IN THIS MEETING, IF THEY ARE NOT, CANCEL THE MEETING. Avoid talking technical stuff in this weekly meeting, keep it only for status discussions on the plan. Follow up with a separate meeting whenever technical issues are raised. Supplement the weekly plan with a list of open items to be closed until the next meeting, ASSIGN AN OWNER to each open item and STATE WHAT IS THE IMPACT of the item on the plan. Pro tip: use color codes, managers love colors (just use Red color sparingly.. )

Tips:

1. Oftentimes, people come with decisions that affect the definition of success (timeline, scope, budget). Remember that only stakeholders are allowed to take such decisions.
2. You cannot control everything/everyone. Focus on being the "guardian" of the actionable plan. Represent this plan in front of the stakeholders and follow up the plan towards closure (definition of success) in front of the participating teams.
3. What you described does not have a simple resolution. Also, there are tons of un-managed projects like you describe in the professional world. If you really want to lead it to a closure, make sure that you apply a methodology for it, to keep things like what, who and when clearer (to you at least).
4. The value of a manager/lead is to bring structure where there is chaos. If you are leading this, remind yourself that you need to be persistent, consistent, structured and determined to reach the goal (definition of success) by getting people to do all the items in your actionable, itemized plan.

Good luck!